# System theme color border for WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, themes, border

I have a custom UserControl and I want it to have the same border style that a normal Window.

I try to bind the border´s color to the system active border color:

```
<UserControl>
     <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="4" >
         <Grid>
```

But that just makes the border gray, no mater what the system border color is.

I want that because I have this userControl inside a maximized, semi-transparent Window, that looks like Dimming the rest of the screen.

Is there other Resource to bind to or another way to achieve that?

Or even is there an easier way to make a 'lights out' effect?

Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that you might be able to set the opacity of your UserControl or the window you are using for the "dimming" effect. This question/answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623661/how-to-add-a-semi-transparent-shade-over-elements-in-wpf

Comment: I think you're going to have to dive into custom chrome and apply that to your usercontrol if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.